# Prosilica GC655C low frame rate

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

My Prosilica GC655C is giving only 56 fps. (The same camera was giving me 89 fps on a different machine, which I don't have access)

My Launch file is:

```
<launch>
<group ns="prosilica">
        <param name="exposure_auto" type="str" value="Auto"/>
    <param name="gain_auto" type="str" value="Auto"/>
    <param name="whitebal_auto" type="str" value="Auto"/>
    <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="high_def_optical_frame" />
        <param name="trigger_mode" type="str" value="streaming"/>
        <param name="ip_address" type="str" value="192.168.0.101"/>
</group>
<node name="prosilica" pkg="prosilica_camera" type="prosilica_node" respawn="false" output="screen">
</node>
```

And I have set my MTU with

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu 8228
```

Is there any thing else that I should check ? (I don't remember doing anything else in the old setup)

FYI: I use CAT 6 cables and the router DLink DIR-825 supports jumbo frames. The current machine is an i7/8GB.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9389/prosilica-gc655c-low-frame-rate/) by [gajan](https://answers.ros.org/users/201/gajan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Gajan,
I've experienced the same with our GC655C, GC660C and GC1290C, in our case changing cable type from CAT5E changed already a lot (our lab should be operational on CAT6A in the following days). Even with CAT5E cable I had to try 4 different types of suppliers before finding a good performance.
I'm still not getting the maximum performance out of our GC660C camera's however. I'm using a Cisco catalyst switch (which doesn't seem to be the bottleneck).

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0